# synonym for zero sum in the world of food

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase that describes drinking a diet coda and eating a candy bar together? I thought of *zero sum game* but it is not exactly what I need because it involves more than one person. I am sending a Secret Santa gift and I need a phrase that describes the habit of eating diet foods along with junk foods.

I have tried talking with some colleagues. I work at a public high school. I do not want to overdo asking others my question because I am concerned that my Secret Santa identity will be compromised. I have tried various internet sites and your site appears to be the most promising in terms of a suitable answer.

My recipient is an IB English teacher.

Comment: What does *zero sum* mean in respect to food? I don't know of any foodstuffs that have negative calories.

Comment: Isn't it something like 'compensation' that you are referring to? Maybe 'caloric' or 'metabolic' or something. But I could be wrong. Completely. You could also speak of a 'well-balanced diet'. Sarcastically.

Comment: Sounds like a *paradox* to me...

Comment: In the question, we need to see exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase – generally we want the sentence you're writing. Specify your criteria for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.). List solutions you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for. See also: “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”.

Comment: Sounds like “Subtraction Stew” from [The Phantom Tollbooth](https://study.com/academy/lesson/subtraction-stew-in-the-phantom-tollbooth.html)  *''How very strange,'' thought Milo as he finished his seventh helping. ''Each one I eat makes me a little hungrier than the one before.''*

Answer (score 1):

[Carbon offsetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_offset) is where a reduction in carbon emissions is made to offset emissions made somewhere else. As an analogy, it sounds as if your colleague is *calorie offsetting*, reducing calories in her soda to offset calories consumed in the chocolate bar.

Otherwise, consider synonyms such as counteracting or balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually said of one-way electronic circuits, but [self-rectifying](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/self-rectification) could be fun—depending on the nerd load and geek factor of your secret Santa recipient.

Commercial low-crab diet foods do this all the time by subtracting fiber-carbs from the other kind to yield “net carbs”.